# how to open the angular UI on a different URL other than localhost

Tags: angular, mean

I am trying to deploy my MEAN stack app on a server at URL `abcd.company.com` with IP `W.X.Y.Z` and running into below error,how do I get it to deploy on the server

```
usernames-MacBook-Pro-2:application username$ ng serve --host W.X.Y.Z
listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 17.208.250.103:4200
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 17.208.250.103:4200
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1262:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1460:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

scripts entry in package.json

  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: change the address from `17.208.250.103:4200` to `0.0.0.0:4200`

Comment: make an entry in hosts file mapping the required address to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: If you are deploying why are you using ng serve.Build the package and deploy in the respective server.

Comment: @Sreemat - how does the server know what html to open for the UI,also its not clear to me how to open the index.html on another URL other than local host,is there any documentation for this?

Comment: You have to deploy the angular application in server like IIS or apache or any other web server.The instance created using ng serve is not for production  or testing purpose it's only for local development.You have generate build using ng build command and deploy it in any web server